# Best place for saving mobile app pin-code

Tags: xcode, mobile, appcelerator

I want to implement a pin-code based security in the app. User will access the app using the pin that s/he created.

Being completely novice to app development I am not sure where is the best place to store the pin.

Some articles say that it can be safely saved in the iPhone keychain. I am not too sure about that as I have seen articles (whether valid or not) about hacking the keychain data.

Please note that I am using Appcelerator. At the moment the app is for iPhone but will be rolling out to other devices later.

Whats the best place for saving the pin? App should work offline which means that online pin verification is not possible.

I am happy to buy something if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iPhone keychain. But another approach can be, not storing the pin as-is rather store a hash (MD5) of the pin. Hence, if the hash of user provided pin matches with the hash of the stored pin matches, it is accepted. Another good thing about storing a hash of the pin is that, it is difficult to get the original data from the hash, hence recovering the original pin will be very difficult.